# Creating view from this query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to create a view from this query? The query is for converting rows into columns. Or if it cant, how to display the values on php?

```
 SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(case when subjectID = ''',
          subjectID,
          ''' then FirstGrading end) AS `',
          subjectID, '`'
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM  view_all_grades_final_edit_last;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT studentID,lname, ', @sql, ' 
                      FROM view_all_grades_final_edit_last 
                      GROUP BY lname');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

Output:

```
    studentID | lname | Computer 101 | History 101 | Java 101 | PE 101 | Science 101
     14-2387      Akbar  0.00           0.00          0.00       0.00     79.93
......
```

Comment: As a note, this sort of thing is a million times easier in a scripting language than in SQL. Your stored procedure has SQL injection bugs in it, too, meaning you should be doing this in PHP with prepared statements that have placeholder values. PHP has [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) which is great for formatting tables, SQL does not.

Comment: Welcome.  The short answer is YES.  The longer answer is, you need to show what you've tried (in PHP), and be specific about what is / is not working.  "How to display the values in php" is not a clear problem statement, but is very broad.

Comment: $sql = ' '; //The query above
`$result = $conn->query($sql);

                                         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                                         echo $row['studentID'];
                                         echo '<br>';
                                         echo $row['lname'];
                                         echo '<br>';
                                         
                                         }`

Comment: Hey, I managed to get the sql command from `@sql ` using `SELECT @sql` then copy and paste the result to make a view table!